# Log Parsing using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, logparser

How can we parse the kind of logs below by using Scala?
I want to read this kind of data and put that into a Hive table.

```
log timestamp=“2018-04-06T22:43:19.565Z” eventCategory=“Application” eventType=“Error”
```

log contents are actually in HTML tag of **< />**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't use Spark/Scala for this. You would sent log data to Solr or Elasticsearch to be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just load the data logs in Hive as-is, though? [Use a RegexSerde in Hive](http://hadooptutorial.info/processing-logs-in-hive/)

Make a directory

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /some/hdfs/path
```

Make a table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logdata;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logdata (
  timestamp STRING,
  eventCategory STRING,
  eventType STRING,
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "log timestamp=\“([^ ]*)\” eventCategory=\“([^ ]*)\” eventType=\“([^ ]*)\”",
  "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/some/hdfs/path/';
```

Upload your logs

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal data.log /some/hdfs/path/
```

Query the table

```
SELECT * FROM logdata;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for response, I want to process this as daily as scheduled jobs also want to filter before inserting into hive/HDFS

Comment: This log data is going to exist on HDFS anyway, no? Just define a raw table as shown here. Use Spark or Hive to filter this table into another table on a daily basis